# Removing "\n" from lists of lines read from .txt files in python with .strip()

Tags: python, list, spyder

I am creating a list from a.txt where each element is a line in the txt file with the code:

```
var_names = []
with open('filevarname.txt', 'r') as f1:
    var_names = f1.readlines()
```

and this does produce the list, however, each element ends with "\n" so the var_names list looks like

```
var_names = [ 'var_name1\n', 'var_name2\n', 'var_name3\n', 'var_name4\n']
```

I have tried to use

```
var_names = map(lambda s: s.strip(), var_names)
```

and

```
var_names = map(lambda line: line.rstrip('\n'), var_names)
```

but when I run those line of codes the lists disappear, it's like it is getting deleted.

I know I'm missing something obvious, but it's not obvious to me so any help would be much appreciated.

I'm using spyder on a mac if that makes a difference.

Comment: `sle_r_name = [x.rstrip() for x in f1]` should do it - no need to `.readlines()` a text file is iterable linewise as is.

Comment: You need a `list()` wrap, if you're working on Python 3: `list(map(lambda s: s.strip(), var_names))`. Note, its not like list is getting deleted, but represented as a `map` object.

Comment: @Austin thanks a million, this worked as well as the answer posted below. Its good to know I can do it in a couple of different ways.

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension:

```
var_names = [x.strip() for x in var_names]
```

Comment: Boom. Thanks a million